# Show login dialog on application resume in iOS

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5

I'm fairly new to iOS development and have an application that requires a login each time you launch the application.  Obviously, the default behavior when resuming the application is to return to the last open view.  I do want this behavior but I need the user to authenticate first and then return them to the last open view so that they can continue their work.  I have seen other applications do this.  Can anyone give me a pointer on the best way to implement this?

Comment: Why do you want to require your user to reauthenticate every time they re-open your app?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html check out applicationWillBecomeActive delegate method. Alternatively, you could logout when applicatonWillResignActive.

Comment: @Maz - The application will contain sensitive data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

This method is called to let your application know that it moved from the inactive to active state. This can occur because your application was launched by the user or the system. Applications can also return to the active state if the user chooses to ignore an interruption (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) that sent the application temporarily to the inactive state.

You should use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. For example, you could use it to restart timers or throttle up OpenGL ES frame rates. If your application was previously in the background, you could also use it to refresh your application’s user interface.

And best way to request login/password is to use UIAlertView ... Here is a comp[lete source code of such dialog imlementation: https://github.com/digdog/DDAlertPrompt ... You have to insert something like this in your applicationDidBecomeActive:

```
DDAlertPrompt *loginPrompt = [[DDAlertPrompt alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sign in to Service"     delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitle:@"Sign In"]; 
[loginPrompt show];
[loginPrompt release];
```

Comment: This is where I was hoping to put the code to do what I need, but I don't understand what I need to do exactly.  I could set the root ViewController to my LoginController, but then I will lose the user's previous state.

Comment: You don't know how to handle UIApplicationDelegate implementation or you don't know how to show your "Login dialog" ?

Comment: I don't know how to show the Login Dialog instead of the current view inside of applicationDidBecomeActive and then once the login is complete, continue where the user left off.  Is there a way to get a reference to the currently active view controller?  If I manage a global reference to the current view controller myself, I could show a modal view on top of it.  Is that the appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Ok. I see... Actually there are many ways to do that. But in your case you don't need to do any magic with views and their controllers, so, the best way is to use standard dialog (I've changed my post)...

Comment: Great, that's probably the way to go for this project actually.  I'll try it out.  You mention many ways to do this, including "magic" with views and controllers.  Out of curiosity, if someone needed to use a View/Controller, what would be the proper way to do that?